# Is it legit or bad practice to move utility methods into abstract superclass?

Tags: java, styles, code-cleanup

I have an interface with its implementation. The public interface methods are using many private methods for doing calculations:

```
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        calc1();
        calc2();
        ...
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        calc1();
        calc2();
        ...
        ...
    }

    private Double calc1() {
        ...
        ...
    }

    private Double calc2() {
        ...
        ...
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

For better overview I separated public interface methods and the utility methods by moving them into an abstract class:

```
public class FooServiceImpl extends AbstractFooService implements FooService {

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        calc1();
        calc2();
        ...
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        calc1();
        calc2();
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

.

```
public abstract class AbstractFooService {

    Double calc1() {
        ...
        ...
    }

    Double calc2() {
        ...
        ...
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Is that a legit pattern or bad practice?

Comment: sure. Well I couldn't name a pattern for that but sure you put everything that is a duplicate in derivations into a parent.  - It's a different story if every derivation needs a different implementation - then the interface may be more appropriate. Also if you additionally want to inherit from something else.

Comment: 1. Please use protected modifier for common methods. 
2. If you use abstract modifier for AbstractFooService then it can also implement FooService. This will allow you to do just extend AbstractFooService in FooServiceImpl. It is resonable only if AbstractFooService will contains common methods for multiple subclasses.Otherwise you don't need to use 'abstract'.